# How to Connect to an MQTT Broker from a JavaScript Client (React) Without Exposing Credentials (username and password)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, backend, mqtt, mosquitto

I am attempting to connect my React application to my Mosquitto MQTT broker securely without exposing my username and password, since anyone has access to the js code and could see the credentials.

The options I've considered so far are as follows:

Using mqtt.js to connect my client directly would expose my username and password. Therefore, I am contemplating building an API that returns my credentials if the user is authenticated (let's say JWT). However, there's a concern that if someone gains access to the user token, they'll be able to retrieve the username and password, making this approach less secure.

Building an API that connects to the MQTT broker, saves the data in MongoDB, and later exposes endpoints to access the data. Although this is what I am currently working on, it seems fundamentally flawed as I may end up losing many advantageous features of MQTT. In this case, it might be worth considering abandoning MQTT altogether.

I was wondering if it is possible to add username and password in the backend and return the mqtt connection to the client, using the backend as some sort of middleware to add the missing information, only if the jwt is valid.

I am aware that I could use a custom plugin for MQTT to validate my JWT token, but I am not inclined towards this option due to the potential added complexity. Building and configuring the broker and the plugin might introduce additional sources of problems.

Comment: Don't include the username and password in the token then... Keep that information stored somewhere else in your server. Then you can use a jwt ( or even better an opaque token) to keep the user authenticated without revealing your user/pass.

Comment: Only you can evaluate your security needs and weigh acceptable risks.  Asking for strangers to do this for you is dangerous.

Comment: @SharpDev In order to connect to an MQTT broker you need to provide a username and a password, If I don't want to expose that username and password I would basically have to make and API and constantly polling the server for data (which the only think that I could come up with). My question is, is it possible to connect to an MQTT broken from the browser, without exposing credentials (username, password).

Comment: @possum I am asking how to safely implement a connection with an MQTT broker from a frontend application (react), without exposing user credentials, nothing to evaluate here.

Comment: What version of MQTT are you using? MQTT 5 introduced ["Enhanced Authentication"](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Enhanced_authentication) which may allow you to authenticate _without_ username & password credentials using new properties on the `CONNECT` packet and an extended handshake with the `AUTH` packet.

Comment: You could modify the password file and signal mosquitto to reload it. You could also proxy the MQTT websocket connection and add authentication details. However these options may well be more work/risk than using a plugin (take a look at [mosquitto-go-auth](https://github.com/iegomez/mosquitto-go-auth)). The optimal approach will depend upon your specific requirements (subscribing from the backend and forwarding relevant messages via another method is a valid option).

Comment: @Brits I guess you are right the only way is to use mosquitto-go-auth or building a backend. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Since it appears security is not a concern and only a method to connect to mqtt directly from yoru client without exposing user credentials is necessary via clarification in the comments, you can disable the need for a username and password entirely in mosquitto entirely by setting in your configuration file (often mosquitto.conf and is dependent on your installation method which was not specified):

```
allow_anonymous true
```

Once you remove your need for credentials there is nothing to expose.

As I said in the comments, only you can evaluate your security needs.  This is dangerous and only a recommendation due to the original author's insistence of finding a method without considering security.